# Sending text view text as an email through a webpage

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, email

So i'm making an app that requires the text that a user types into a TextView to be emailed to an email through an API. I already have an API set up and I asked the owner of it on how I would send the email in Xcode. This was his reply:

"Re the email API... You could actually piggy back onto the API that exists on the website already....

If you sent a POST variable 'message_txt' to http://www.fakewebaddress.com/email.php" it should send the email"

Now being new to developing I struggled to find a way to do this.

So to recap what I'm asking: How would I get text from a TextView to be sent through the above link?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a UITextView to your UI. Then declare it in your header (.h) file like so:

```
IBOutlet UITextView *emailText;
```

Then link the UITextView to emailText in Interface Builder. Then in your implementation file (.m) file, make a method which can be used to send the POST request to the PHP file like so:

```
-(void)sendEmail {

    NSString *post = emailText.text;
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fakewebaddress.com/email.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
}
```

**Note**

I would like to add that you have NOT specified how your PHP file will be taking in the text data. Does it want it as part of the body (maybe a JSON file) OR is it taking in queries (part of the URL)? The example I have added, adds the data to the POST| request body.

**Update**

Sorry I didn't notice that you wanted it in Swift. Here is an example of a POST request in Swift:

```
func sendEmail() {

    let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.fakewebaddress.com/email.php")
    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
    NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)

    // set data
    var dataString = emailText.text
    let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

    // set content length
    //NSURLProtocol.setProperty(requestBodyData.length, forKey: "Content-Length", inRequest: request)

    var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

    let results = NSString(data:reply!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("API Response: \(results)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though, I've been learning swift so this is not very familiar to me. Is there an easy way to convert it?